# XML shape drawable not rendering desired color

Tags: android, drawable

I defined a `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
  <size android:width="60dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

But how to use it in the `layout` definition?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I still see only black background.

**Edited:**

It turned out I missed one `:` in the `drawable` `xmlns` declaration. Now this example works in the Gingerbread device :)

Comment: Silly question, but is `ic_title` the name of the drawable you defined? Also, you can set `android:background` on the `LinearLayout`

Comment: yes, ic_title is the drawable I defined above. I don't want to set android:background, that's not the desired effect. I may put more ImageView into the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found that if you remove the size definition, it works for some reason.

Remove:

```
<size
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

from the shape.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: But a shape without the size definition, it's same as filling the background of the ImageView.

Comment: True. Then I would assume that you need a container to hold that image view, which sets it's own size to the size you need - that is what my example does - i.e. I declare a relative layout with a size and then just put my imageView inside that.

Comment: Haha! I found your problem :D I hope you give me my first kudos for this ;)

You have a Typo in your shape definition. Look at the following and spot the missing ":" after http:

"http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Oh, that is weird. I should check if this typo really presents in my test code. Kudos to you anyway :)

Answer (score 21):

In drawable I use this xml code to define the border and background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#D8FDFB" /> 
  <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
    android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
  <corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
  <solid android:color="#f0600000"/> 
</shape>
```